# How to add column in a table on fly?

Tags: sql, mysql

i want to add two tables. But how should i distinguish that which entries is from which table?

### table1

```
col1 
-----
a
b
c
```

### table 2

```
1
2
3
```

The result should be:

```
col1 tablename
----------------
a     table1
b      "
c      "
d     table2
e      "
f      "
```

Comment: Alis, you didn't accept our previous answers! Explain yourself!

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Table1.Col1, "Table1" as 'TableName'
From dbo.Table1

Union all

Select Table2.Col1, "Table2" as 'TableName'
From dbo.Table2
```